# How do I delay jQuery Cycle from going until it is in the main window?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I have a jQuery cycle in the third panel of this [site](http://cleverwitz.com/dev/). I would like to delay it playing until the viewer is actually at that point.

I tried a LazyLoader, but Cycle ignores that.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-loop="1">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-01.jpg" alt="slide-01" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-02.jpg" alt="slide-02" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-03.jpg" alt="slide-03" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-04.jpg" alt="slide-04" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-05.jpg" alt="slide-05" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-06.jpg" alt="slide-06" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-07.jpg" alt="slide-07" class="img-responsive lazy">
            <img src="/dev/images/slide-08.jpg" alt="slide-08" class="img-responsive lazy">
</div><!-- end slideshow -->
```

I don't have to use the following Lazyload code (especially since it isn't working in the current circumstances), but I am open to solutions.

```
 <script src="/dev/resources/js/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>
 <script>
      $(function() {
         $("img.lazy").lazyload();
         });
      </script>
```

Comment: you would need to remove the attributes and properties that auto initialize it and manually initialize instead. See docs on how to manually initialize

Comment: could you shed some light on that?